# navigation.goBack() not working in nested navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-tabnavigator, react-native-drawer

my screens are arranged this way:

main root
Stack navigator has 2 screens

1. Login
2. Drawer

The drawer is a Drawer Navigator, having three screens

1. Home
2. Profile
3. Settings

Home is a Bottom Tab Navigator having multiple Screens like

1. Dashboard
2. Reminder
   etc ...

So the issue is whenever I am in any sub-screen of let's say reminder and I want to close it by navigation.goBack() it takes me to Dashboard, what I want is to land back on reminder

PS. the sub screen is also in the tab navigator I have hidden it with filter

Answer (score 1):

Read the following code and try it, don't forget to import it.
The way I've done it is putting the drawer above in the file
**DrawerNavigator.js**:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return(
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='TabNavigator'>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={TabNavigator}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Profile' component={ProfileStackScreen}/> 
        <Drawer.Screen name='Settings' component={SettingsStackScreen}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

export default DrawerNavigator
```

Here I insert the TabNavigator(Only one of the options in the Drawer will have te bottom tab navigator, the *Home* one.
The **TabNavigator.js** will have all the bottom tab screens:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Dashboard'>
                <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboarStackScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name='Reminder' component={ReminderStackScreen}/>
          </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default BottomTabNavigator
```

In the **StackNavigator.js** you will enter every stack screens you might want to use:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const DashboardStackScreen = () => {

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator >
    {/*INSERT STACK SCREENS HERE*/}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}


const ReminderStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator  >
    {/*INSERT STACK SCREENS HERE*/}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}


const ProfileStackScreen = () => {
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator  >
      {/*INSERT STACK SCREENS HERE*/}
    </Stack.Navigator>
    
  )
}

const SettingsStackScreen = () => {
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator >
      {/*INSERT STACK SCREENS HERE*/}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export {DashboardStackScreen,ReminderStackScreen,ProfileStackScreen,SettingsStackScreen}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StackNavigator for each tab of the BottomTabNavigator, which contains the screens for that tab. Every tab will then have its own navigation stack.

Comment: can you share an example i'd highly appreciate

Comment: The documentation of React Navigation is pretty good, they have an example of a tabNavigator with nested stackNavigators [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab).